# Missing an option to use SQL's HAVING clause in F3

Tags: mysql, fat-free-framework

Is there a way to use MySQL's HAVING clause with any of [Fat Free Framework's SQL Mapper object's](https://fatfreeframework.com/sql-mapper) methods? Let's assume I have the following DB table:

```
+----+-------+--------+
| id | score | weight |
+----+-------+--------+
|  2 |     1 |      1 |
|  2 |     2 |      3 |
|  2 |     3 |      1 |
|  2 |     2 |      2 |
|  3 |     1 |      4 |
|  3 |     3 |      1 |
|  3 |     4 |      3 |
+----+-------+--------+
```

Now I would like to run a following query:

```
SELECT id, SUM(score*weight)/SUM(weight) AS weighted_score GROUP BY id HAVING weighted_score>2
```

Truth to be told I would actually like to count the number of these records, but a `count` method doesn't support `$options`.

I can run the query without a `HAVING` clause and then loop through them to check `weighted_score` against the value, but with a growing number of records will make it more and more resource consuming. Is there any built-in solution to solve this problem?

EDIT 1:
The way I know how to do it if there is no support for the `HAVING` clause (based on [manual](https://fatfreeframework.com/databases#SeekandYouShallFind)):

```
$databaseObject = new DB\SQL(...);
$dataMapper = new \DB\SQL\Mapper($databaseObject, "tableName");
$dataMapper->weightedScore = "SUM(weight*score)/SUM(weight)";
$usersInfo = $dataMapper->find([],["group"=>"id"]);
$place = 1;
foreach ( $usersInfo as $userInfo ) {
    if ( $usersScores->weightedScore > 2) $place++;
}
```

If I were able to use `HAVING` clause then the foreach loop would not be needed and the number of items loaded by a query would be reduced:

```
$databaseObject = new DB\SQL(...);
$dataMapper = new \DB\SQL\Mapper($databaseObject, "tableName");
$dataMapper->weightedScore = "SUM(weight*score)/SUM(weight)";
$usersInfo = $dataMapper->find([],["group"=>"id", "having"=>"weighted_score<2"]); // rough idea
$place = count($usersInfo);
```

And if [`count` method](https://fatfreeframework.com/sql-mapper#count) supported `$options` it would be even simpler and it would save memory used by the app as no records would be loaded:

```
$databaseObject = new DB\SQL(...);
$dataMapper = new \DB\SQL\Mapper($databaseObject, "tableName");
$dataMapper->weightedScore = "SUM(weight*score)/SUM(weight)";
$place = $dataMapper->count([],["group"=>"id", "having"=>"weighted_score<2"]); // rough idea
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Sub Query.

```
select count (0) from (SELECT id, SUM(score*weight)/SUM(weight) AS weighted_score GROUP BY id) where weighted_score>2;
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: True, but this is still plain vanilla SQL. What I wanted to know is if it can be done with a Fat Free Framework's SQL mapper. It extends PHP PDO, so maybe there is a way to do it on the PDO level... I will update my question with an example of how I would like to be able to be done and how I need to do it until I will get a tip here.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can put the HAVING clause into the group option:

```
$usersInfo = $dataMapper->find([],["group"=>"id HAVING weighted_score<2"]);
```

Another way could be to create a VIEW in mysql and filter the records on a virtual fields in that view.

Comment: I was pretty sure I tried that (after I looked at the code of the library and noticed the regular expression which includes `having` clause), but it wasn't working for me. I will double check and let you know

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working. And DB [log](https://fatfreeframework.com/sql#log) shows no difference between a query run with and without a `having` clause.

Comment: Looks like this feature has vanished 1 year ago and nobody noticed ^^ https://github.com/bcosca/fatfree-core/commit/4b3faa056ebd67c866ddf2dc6c70da01b73095fd

Comment: Fixed in https://github.com/bcosca/fatfree-core/commit/a66023edc37115e8c1bd4d4eedfa7a3358e0dd5c

Comment: Thanks ^^ I will give it a try